# How to fix RSS Viewer Web Part error due to bad / invalid xml?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, rss

I'm encountering the error below in my RSS Viewer Web Part:

```
Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://pagasa.dost.gov.ph/index.php/news?format=feed&type=rss.

Enter:IsIntranetAddress - Trying to find IP address of server name 'pagasa.dost.gov.ph'.

Exit:IsIntranetAddress - IP address of server name 'pagasa.dost.gov.ph' is 'not found'.
[Outbound] [SPWebRequest] Http request created. Mark='C0ec6b19d-36fd-c005-dd2e-afd42cb83f11', App='None', TypeName='System.Exception', InstanceTag='unknown', OutboundUrl='http://pagasa.dost.gov.ph/index.php/news?format=feed&type=rss'.

RssWebPart: Exception handed to HandleRuntimeException.HandleException System.Xml.XmlException: The 'br' start tag on line 1 position 180 does not match the end tag of 'body'. Line 1, position 235. 
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) 
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag) 
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement() 
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() 
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace) 
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc) 
    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) 
    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.Execute(String request) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXm...
```

The RSS Feed I am trying to access is this: http://pagasa.dost.gov.ph/index.php/news?format=feed&type=rss

I think the 'br' tag the web part is referring to if you go to the XML file is because they are encoding their 'br' tags as "</br>". I've tried with some online RSS Viewers and most of them seem to handle it fine. I've also confirmed that my RSS Viewer Web Part is working fine by trying out more simple feeds and it successfully displays them.

I also tried running below code:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.Properties.DisableIntranetCalls = $false
$farm.Properties.DisableIntranetCallsFromApps = $false
$farm.Update()
```

But the only thing that happened was that the error messages "Enter:IsIntranetAddress" and "Exit:IsIntranetAddress" were gone. The main error regarding the XmlException and others was still there.

How do I go about on fixing this? Is this really an RSS Viewer Web Part limitation? If so, what are alternatives to this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently facing the same/similar problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. The webpart for RSS feeds only works if the source site provides a url with a .xml extension. I don't know the solution, but I third that this is an important problem and would love to know of a work-around.